# How to embed website via IFRAME in IONIC APP?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic5

I am trying to embed an already developed website into ionic 5 application via an IFRAME.

The application is displaying the website as well as expected but when I try to use Login Form, nothing happens, it just reload the page and no message no login ...

Could you help me please ?

```js
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {DomSanitizer} from '@angular/platform-browser';

const URL = 'https://pusso.technokocc.fr' ;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['home.page.scss'],
})
export class HomePage implements OnInit{

  safeUrl: any ;

  constructor(private domSanit: DomSanitizer) {
    this.safeUrl = this.getSafeUrl() ;
  }

  getSafeUrl(){
    return this.domSanit.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(URL) ;
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.safeUrl = this.getSafeUrl() ;
  }

  ionViewWillEnter(){
    this.safeUrl = this.getSafeUrl() ;
  }

}
```

```css
ion-content div.scroll{
  height: 90%;
}

.webPage{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: transparent;
  overflow: hidden ;
}
```

```html
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-title>
      Pusso
    </ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content [fullscreen]="true">
  <iframe class= 'webPage' frameborder="0" name="eventsPage" [src]="safeUrl" allowfullscreen>
  </iframe>
</ion-content>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ionic team said, `I would not suggest using an iframe.`

https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/right-approach-to-embed-third-party-web-application-into-ionic-mobile-app/192153/6

I coudn't understand this reason completely. But I guess iframe cause unexpected issues.

---

If you don't have to preserve footer or header, you can try this. It looks like modal.

### Cordova-in-app-browser

https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/in-app-browser

This can hide url bar and have many options :
https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser#cordovainappbrowseropen

`this.iab.create('https://url', '_self', 'location=no,fullscreen=no')`

not to open new browser window, add this

```
// capacitor.config.ts
server: {
  allowNavigation: ['your-domain']
}
```

### Capacitor Browser

https://capacitorjs.com/docs/apis/browser

But, `13.2.4 ver` can't hide url bar.